# Qual a boa prática ao lançar exceção dentro de if?

Tags: java, if, else, exceção

Qual a melhor prática neste caso, utilizar o **else** mesmo sabendo que o **if** vai lançar exceção ou não?

opção 1 (com **else**):

```java
if (condicao){
  throw new RuntimeException("Mensagem");
}else{
  System.out.println("Não deu exception");
}
```

opção 2 (sem **else**):

```java
if (condicao){
  throw new RuntimeException("Mensagem");
}
System.out.println("Não deu exception");
```

Comment: Só "descompilando" o *bytecode* pra saber... Eu acredito que ambas as formas são equivalentes, de modo que um critério para escolher entre um e outro seria subjetivo e/ou variaria caso a caso.

Comment: Essa pergunta ficaria melhor no [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @karlphillip provavelmente se um dia tivermos um codereview em pt, ela será migrada.

Comment: @Bacco Em outras palavras, o que você está sugerindo é que o pt.SO abrigue perguntas que seriam próprias para Code Review, Programmers, Signal Processing, Superuser, Serverfault, Webmasters e Game Development só porque não existe um fórum dedicado para cada tema em português? Isso vai virar uma confusão enorme...

Comment: @karlphillip Mas eu não sugeri nada! :). Quanto a essa discussão, foi bem extensa tanto no meta quanto na área 51, sugiro uma olhada em ambos, em especial o http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com. Em resumo, aqui os limites são mais amplos, mas algumas questões realmente fora de tópico já foram fechadas até. De qualquer forma a comunidade ainda está procurando seu ponto de equilíbrio, e você pode com certeza contribuir no meta ( http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com ) com sua opinião, que é o melhor caminho.

Comment: @Bacco Thank you very much, Sir. ;)

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão, se você estiver lançando `IllegalArgumentException` e similares, vale a pena usar uma biblioteca de pré-condições como o [Preconditions do Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) ou [Validate do Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/Validate.html). Essa bibliotecas removem a necessidade do if e tornam o código bem mais legível.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Embora isso esteja propenso a um forte senso de opinião pessoal, eu acredito que a melhor prática é **não** utilizar bloco o `else`.

As razões são as seguintes:

### Legibilidade do código

Acrescentar blocos aninhados, embora neste pequeno exemplo não cause um grande impacto, somente irá dificultar a leitura do código e torná-lo mais complexo.

Na prática, isso pode levar a situações com vários níveis de validação, como eu já vi por vezes em sistemas por aí:

```java
if (condicao1){
    throw new RuntimeException("Mensagem 1");
}else{
    System.out.println("Não deu exception 1");
    if (condicao1){
        throw new RuntimeException("Mensagem 2");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Ainda não deu exception 2");
        if (condicao1){
            throw new RuntimeException("Mensagem 3");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ainda não deu exception 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Para quem pensa que estou exagerando, não foram uma ou duas vezes que vi métodos com validações de 5, 6 ou mais níveis em métodos de sistemas financeiros com regras de negócio um tanto complexas.

### Não é necessário

Uma condição que inclua um lançamento de exceção, ou outra instrução que venha a interromper a execução do método não precisa deste tipo de construção. Código desnecessário é perda de tempo.

### É melhor separar as validações iniciais

As validações iniciais de um método não precisam e provavelmente não devem influenciar na lógica principal do método.

```java
public int meuMetodo(String parametro) {

    if (parametro == null || parametro.isEmpty()) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parâmetro não informado!");

    //lógica aqui
    return 123;

}
```

Comment: Nâo é boa prática deixar um if sem {}. Inclusive no livro Java Coding Guidelines pode levar a problemas de segurança.

Comment: Questão de *coding style*! É perfeitamente aceitável **não** usar chaves quando o `if` deve executar apenas um comando, e o *coding style* da pessoa exige que ela pule uma linha logo após as instruções do `if`, como foi o caso do exemplo acima.

Comment: @uaiHebert Concordo, geralmente eu não faço isso. Pra falar a verdade eu nem reparei enquanto digitava. Em Java isso pode levar, por exemplo, a pensarmos que a indentação vai colocar dois comando dentro do `if`. O problema é que estou estudando Python, então já viu... :S

Answer (score 12):

Do ponto de vista da performance, não há razões para se escolher entre uma e outra, a diferença deve ser negligível. Ainda que a representação das duas formas no [*bytecode*](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/flowP.html) seja distinta, a performance será muitíssimo semelhante, com diferença de uns poucos ciclos quando muito (em contraste, um *cache miss* na L1 "desperdiça" 10-40 ciclos, na L2 mais de 600).

Do ponto de vista da legibilidade, creio que vai depender da semântica do seu programa. Se a condição `if` se refere a um caso excepcional, creio que o ideal é omitir o `else`:

```java
if ( denominador == 0 )
    throw new RuntimeException("Não pode dividir por zero");
quociente = numerador / denominador;
```

Por outro lado, se a condição `if` fizer parte de um conjunto mutuamente excludente, então creio que seria interessante incluir o `else` (ou talvez até mesmo um `else if`):

```java
if ( x < 10 )
    return foo(x);
else if ( 10 <= x && x <= 20 )
    throw new RuntimeException("x não pode estar dentro do intervalo");
else if ( 20 < x )
    return bar(x);
// else
//     throw new RuntimeException("Isso nunca deve acontecer");
```

Comment: Nâo é boa prática deixar um if sem {}. Inclusive no livro Java Coding Guidelines pode levar a problemas de segurança.

Comment: @uaiHebert Prefiro deixar cada um escolher seu próprio estilo de codificação. Pessoalmente, essa sintaxe me desagrada, mas se a comunidade Java tiver isso como consenso (não saberia dizer, pois faz anos que não trabalho com essa linguagem) sintam-se livres para editar meu código de exemplo.

Comment: @Bacco Eu normalmente trabalho com Python, que não possui `{ }` e usa a edentação para definir blocos. Se eu hoje fosse programar em Java, provavelmente ia esquecer que `{ }` existe (da mesma forma que costumo esquecer de colocar `;` no final das instruções) e criaria um `if` com múltiplas instruções. O problema é: somente a primeira estará dentro do `if`, as demais estarão fora. Isso é um erro comum, e muita gente sugere nunca omitir o `{ }` por causa disso (concordar ou não é outra história). Essa é uma razão, embora não saiba a que o uaiHibert se refere quando diz "problemas de segurança".

Comment: @mgibsonbr até entendo o que você disse, e inclusive eu as vezes distraio quando misturo por exemplo, Harbour e C no mesmo source, e esqueço o ";" na parte C. Agora, dizer que usar if sem {} não é boa prática ja me soa um tanto prepotente. É como usar OOP ou não. Não tem melhor, quem sabe usar os dois usa no lugar certo e do jeito certo, conforme a linguagem permite, e fica bom.

Answer (score 7):

O seu `if` é uma "guard clause": uma cláusula que, se verdadeira, impede a execução do resto do código do método (ou de um loop). *Guard clauses* sempre contêm código de "pulo", como `return`, `throw`, `break` ou `continue`. Elas servem como pré-condições para execução de certos blocos de código.

Minha *opinião pessoal* é de que essas cláusulas não precisam de `else`, já que o código vai "pular" fora mesmo:

```
if (condicao) throw new RuntimeException("Oops");

.... resto do código
```

Imagine um método com muitas pré-condições, usando `else` faria o código mais ilegível.

Note que também faço o seguinte para "Guard Clauses":

- deixo o código do `if` e do "pulo" na mesma linha
- não uso um bloco delimitado com `{}`

Veja uma [resposta a uma pergunta semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021329/31158) que fiz no SO.

No clássico livro Refactoring de Martin Fowler, existe uma [refatoração para transformar de condicionais aninhados para *guard clauses*](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

Answer (score 5):

Na minha opinião, quanto menos **contexto** melhor. Em geral, um contexto diferente é iniciado com `{` e finalizado com `}`, e do ponto de vista de quem lê o código, equivale a coisas do passado que devem ser lembradas para que o código possa ser compreendido.

Por exemplo:

```java
public int metodo(int parametro) {
    if (parametero < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
        // Estamos no contexto do else que está dentro do contexto do método.
        // Ou seja, você tem que ter estes dois contextos em mente.
        return 42 + parametro;
    }
}
```

Já aqui:

```java
public int metodo(int parametro) {
    if (parametero < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    // Estamos no contexto do método, fora de qualquer if ou else.
    return 42 + parametro;
}
```

Isso se torna bastante evidente em códigos como este:

```java
public boolean validaCPF(String cpf) {
    if (cpf == null || cpf.length() != 11) {
        return false;
    } else {
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int c = cpf.charAt(i) - '0';
            if (c < 0 || c > 9) {
                return false;
            } else {
                a += c * (i + 1);
                b += c * (9 - i);
            }
        }
        a = (a % 11) % 10;
        b = (b % 11) % 10;
        if (cpf.charAt(9) - '0' == a && cpf.charAt(10) - '0' == b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Que fica muito melhor assim:

```java
public boolean validaCPF(String cpf) {
    if (cpf == null || cpf.length() != 11) return false;

    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int c = cpf.charAt(i) - '0';
        if (c < 0 || c > 9) return false;
        a += c * (i + 1);
        b += c * (9 - i);
    }
    a = (a % 11) % 10;
    b = (b % 11) % 10;
    return cpf.charAt(9) - '0' == a && cpf.charAt(10) - '0' == b;
}
```

Isso demonstra que se o else puder ser evitado, o código fica mais limpo.